# regex maps all of my words (even if duplicated)

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to use a regex that maps certain words, and show a tooltip with a definition. it actually works fine except for one things.

if i write the same words 2 times, the tooltip is added 2 times (that is not a good experience for an user)

my actual regex:

```
 regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + Object.keys(mappings).join('|') + ')\\b(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*</[^p])', 'gi');
```

if i replace 'gi' with 'i', he parse only 1 word (even it there are different words inside the post)

any help on this?

this is what i want to avoid:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIeqT.png)

Comment: Using a loop to match each single word once with its own regex might be easier

Comment: can u provide me a working example? (i'm trying everything without success)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter each word in your mapping that appears in your input. Each one with its own regex:

```js
const mappings = {
    api: "Application Programming Interface",
    cookie: "Yummy",
    flarum: "I don't know what this is",
    javascript: "... Is to Java what Hamster is to Ham"
  },
  input = "Here is an API. But not any API! This one is all about flarum!",
  words = Object.keys(mappings).filter(w => {
    const regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + w + ')\\b(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*</[^p])', 'i');
    return regex.test(input);
  });

console.log(words);
```

Comment: exactly what i need. this works perfectly!

Comment: Looks like complexity O(input*mappings), but I like this solution

Answer (score 0):

De-duplicate outside of the regex.
You can do this manually, or using a `Set`

```
const words = [...(new Set(input.matchAll(regex)) ).values()];
```

Breaking this down:

`input.matchAll(regex)` return iterator of all results

`new Set()` create new Set of the results (duplicate entries will be dropped)

`().values()` get an iterator of the values in the Set

`[... ]` create a new array using the returned iterator

## Alternatives

Regex is not always the best way to go. In this case a regex is being constructed dynamically, which might be a red flag that this approach is not ideal.

Another approach might be to create a loop over every word in your `mappings` and search for each. The resulting code will be less efficient (take longer to run) but be easier to read.

Comment: thanks i will work on this, i hope that will works!

Comment: actually i'm trying but i'm really bad...could u help me with a working example when u have some time?

Answer (score 0):

my last try was:

```
  let regex;

  if (app.forum.attribute('ParseOnce') === true) {
    regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + Object.keys(mappings).join('|') + ')\\b(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*</[^p])', 'i');
  } else {
    regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + Object.keys(mappings).join('|') + ')\\b(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*</[^p])', 'gi');
  }
```

but do not know your method (i'm not professional developer sorry for this) can u provide me a working example?